# re-quote string passed to bash function

Tags: string, bash, git, function

I'm trying to create a function that creates a git commit.

```
function commit_thing {
    git add $1
    shift
    git commit $@
}
```

I can't quote $@, because I'm trying to retain the ability to create both a subject and a body for a commit.  For example:

```
commit_thing thing1.txt -m "This is a subject" -m "This is a detailed body"
```

How should I pass the remaining variables in such a way as to quote the ones originally passed in quotes to the function, while not quoting the flags that need to be passed to the git commit command?

Comment: Use single quotes 'THis is a subject'

Comment: If your example is really what you want to achieve you do not need a function, it will work with: `git commit -m "This is a subject" -m "This is a detailed body" thing1.txt`

Comment: Quoting `$@` is exactly how you accomplish this; that's the reason for `$@` to exist along side `$*`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek it's actually more abusive of git than just trying to do that, so not a good 1-to-1 example, but the impact is the same.

Comment: @chepner That's what I get for not testing it and misunderstanding how it worked.

Comment: @NDGeek I am not saying it is a good idea to do that (I always recommend quite the contrary) I am just saying that if this is really its function, it is not needed as `git` can do it in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of `$@` is to allow individual arguments to remain quoted yet distinct. Compare

```
$ set -- "a b" "c d"
$ printf '%s\n' "$*"
a b c d
$ print '%s\n' "$@"
a b
c d
```

So you would simply write

```
function commit_thing {
    git add "$1"
    shift
    git commit "$@"
}
```

With a command like `commit_thing thing1.txt -m "This is a subject" -m "This is a detailed body"`, the 5 arguments are `thing1.txt`, `-m`, `This is a subject`, `-m`, and `This is a detailed body`. After the shift, `"$@"` will pass the remaining arguments as-is to `git commit` *as* separate arguments, not as one single argument as `"$*"` would.